# In JavaFX, is there a way to get a reference to a component just by the position of the component?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently experimenting a bit with JavaFX user interfaces and automated testing of these.

For my current experiments with graphical component recognition in a GUI, I get the position of a component and can at least perform mouse interactions on the component. However, I would also like to perform actions like reading and comparing the text inside a text field or to read or change any other properties of a JavaFX GUI component.

Therefore I was wondering, if there was any way to ask any managing instance of JavaFX for the reference to the component at a specified position.

Comment: do you want to get a link to the object by screen coordinates?

Comment: It sounds a little like you are trying to replicate [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX). If you just need automated testing functionality, I'd just use that... If you are interested in how to implement it as an exercise, it is open source, so you can look at how they did it.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no direct way to do that but you can iterate over the scene graph and ask every node for its bounds in local, transform that into scene coordinates via its local to scene transform and then compare that with your position which also has to be in scene coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates are attributes of individual nodes (the elements in the [Scene Graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm)), so won't by itself give you access to the nodes. You could, however, use the `getChildren()` method on a [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) to iterate through that Pane's nodes to get to a particular node's coordinates.